# Text color for label not changing when I use custom UIColors

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

So, my code works fine when I do something like this:

```
let label = UILabelBuiler("1", backgroundColor: UIColor.redColor(), textColor: UIColor.whiteColor(), font: UIFont(name: "FuturaStd-Heavy", size: 11)!)
```

But it does nothing when I do this:

```
let label = UILabelBuiler("1", backgroundColor: UIColor(red: 255, green: 75, blue: 75, alpha: 1), textColor: UIColor(red: 185, green: 200, blue: 202, alpha: 1), font: UIFont(name: "FuturaStd-Heavy", size: 11)!)
```

Here is what it looks like when I use the first one:

[image]

and here is the second one (that doesn't show up)

[image]

And my UILabelBuilder function looks like this:

```
func UILabelBuiler(labelText: String, backgroundColor: UIColor, textColor: UIColor, font: UIFont) -> UILabel {
   let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(218, 14, 15, 20))
   label.text = labelText
   label.numberOfLines = 0
   label.sizeToFit()
   label.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
   label.textColor = textColor
   label.font = font


   return label
}
```

Additionally, does anyone know off the top of their head how I could round the label's background?

Comment: and the `UILabelBuiler(...)` is...? or does...? or what...?

Comment: then more likely... `UIColor(red: 255.0 / 255.0, green: 75.0 / 255.0, blue: 75.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1)` for the custom colours, I presume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color components of `UIColor` are defined as

> The {red, green, blue, alpha} component of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0
>   to 1.0.

Adjust the values accordingly or divide each of them by 255.0

Answer (score 1):

When creating a color, the rgba values it expects are floats in the range `0...1` so you can either enter the colors as floats or by dividing by `255`

```
UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.29, blue: 0.29, alpha: 1.0)

UIColor(red: 255.0 / 255.0, green: 75.0 / 255.0, blue: 75.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```